# Linux play video command freezes after a few seconds

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, javafx, mpv

I run a shell command in a Java jar application, I use Runtime and process exec, but after some minutes the video and the java process freezes.

When I run the command alone in shell console it works fine.

In console it works:

```
ffplay -loglevel debug -autoexit -af volume=0.8  /home/fasepi/Vd_bn_cronometro_deportivo.mp4
```

the problem arises when I run this command in a java jar:

```
String playVideoCommand="ffplay -loglevel debug -autoexit -af volume=0.8  "+outputPath;

Process pr = rt.exec(playVideoCommand);
pr.waitFor();
```

I run this in Ubuntu 16.04
Java Openjdk 8

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting this before you execute your command to use graphics acceleration

```
System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl","True");
```